# All paths between two nodes in unweighted undirected graph with bounded number of edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have unweighted directed graph G which maybe very large (thousands of nodes).

I am interested in finding all possible paths(without cycles) between specific two nodes with limited number of edges ( at maximum the path contains 10 edges). Is there any fast algorithm which can deal with this large graph.

Comment: Is the graph dense? IOW, is the number of edges linear or quadratic in the number of nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify dfs to solve this problem. Simply add another parameter - the depth at which you currently are, then cut the dfs if the path length limit was reached before target node `target`. To demonstrate the idea I will use recursive implementation and I will use a global array `used` - the nodes visited this far on the way. Also I will assume that we've stored the graph using neighborhood list representation(let's call that `neList`, the neighbors of node v are at neList[v]):

```
used[n] = {false}
neList; // neighborhoodList
limit = 10 // max path len
void dfs(int v, int depth) {
  if (depth == limit) {
    if (v == target) {
       print_path
    } else {
       return
    }
  }
  for u in neList[v] {
    if (used[u]) {
      continue;
    }
    used[u] = true
    dfs(u, depth + 1)
    used[u] = false
  }
}
```

You can optimize this approach a bit - first do a bfs from the target node to compute min_distance between `target` and all nodes. In the `dfs` only go to a neighbor `u` if `depth + min_dist[u] <= limit`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it efficiently in the worst case. Imagine a full graph. Let's count the number of paths with exactly 10 edges. It is `1 * (n - 2) * (n - 3) * ... * (n - 9) * 1 = O(n ^ 8)`. It is too much for a graph with a few thousands of nodes.

Comment: But you managed to compute that number without counting them one at a time. So the fact that the number of possible paths is large does not imply that it cannot be computed efficiently.

Comment: @rici According to my understanding, find all paths means not just to count them, but rather print them all.

Comment: If you had to print them it could take a lot of paper :) But even so, there might be an efficient algorithm to enumerate them, which might be reasonable if the graph is not dense. But it's true that "find" probably means more than "count".

Answer (score 0):

I would second @Ivaylo Strandjev's answer. The problem is `all-simple paths` problem. Backtracking is the way to go. Backtracking is just DFS where at certain point the algorithm *backtracks* to the previous node. Your requirement of max(length)=10 is the backtracking point. Here is general description:

1. Start with any vertex `v`
2. Examine `v` children till you get your
   target or have exceed the path length requirement
3. backtrack.

This will find all paths of length at most 10 from `(v,u)` for any target vertex `u`.
The number of paths could be exponential( I think it's NP-hard problem not too sure). Efficient algorithm depends upon your domain knowledge. You may incorporate heuristics to prone  unpromising nodes.